# Module '"node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing routing in my angular meteor app but gets typescript error of that  `Module '"node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'.` and `Module '"node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'Routes'`
Any help will really be grateful.

app.routes file is 
`import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`
`import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';`
`import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';`
`import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component';` 
`import { MyApp } from './app.component';`
`export const routes: Routes=[`
`{path:'',component:MyApp},`
`{path:'login',component:LoginComponent},`
`{path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},`
`{path:'resources',component:ResourcesComponent},`
 
`];`

package.json 
`{`
`"name": "test",`
`"private": true,`
`"scripts": {`
`"start": "meteor run"`
`},`
`"dependencies": {`
`"@angular/common": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/core": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/http": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.3",`
`"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",`
`"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",`
`"babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",`
`"meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",`
`"meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",`
`"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",`
`"rxjs": "^5.4.1",`
`"zone.js": "^0.8.12"`
`},`
`"devDependencies": {`
`"@types/meteor": "^1.4.2",`
`"@types/meteor-accounts-phone": "0.0.5",`
`"@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",`
`"meteor-typings": "^1.3.1"`
`}`
`}`

Comment: are you using system.config?

Comment: I dont think so but package.json

Answer (score 0):

In your app.route module add this

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
{path:'',component:MyApp},
{path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
{path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},
{path:'resources',component:ResourcesComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRouteModule {
}
```

and in your app.module import this module

```
import { AppRouteModule } from './app.route.module';
```

and register the module

```
@NgModule({
...
imports: [ AppRouteModule ],
...
})
export class AppModule{
}
```

Comment: Thats not the problem because it was implemented and did no good. Please any other solution will be really helpful.